# Is there some way to know if the text of an entry is from a copy paste or from a text written by the user?

Tags: maui

I have a MAUI application and an entry control.

If the user write text, I would like to do something and if the text comes from a copy paste action, I would like to do another thing.

Is it possible to know if the text of an entry is from a copy paste action or from a write text? I have search some event that could be paste or something like that but I don't see any that could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: you could check if the value of the entry matches the value of the clipboard contents

Comment: Yes, it is a good option. Thanks so much.

Comment: You could use TextChanged event. If it grows by a single character, its probably the user typing. If it grows by multiple characters, its a paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By comparing the value of the entry to the value of the clipboard contents directly, the results obtained are not necessarily correct.

If we enter one charter and the clipboard contents contains the same charter,we don't know if the new string is coming from a copy paste or from a text written by the user.

Just as ToolmakerSteve mentioned, you can use `Entry_TextChanged` event to judge,if it grows by multiple characters, the input should come from clipboard contents.

Please refer to the following code:

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
{
         if (e.NewTextValue != null)
            {
                  if (e.OldTextValue != null)
                  {
                        if (e.NewTextValue.Length - e.OldTextValue.Length > 1)
                        {
                              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("---> new string come from clipboard contents");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("---> get one charter....");

                     }
              }
            }
      }
```

Comment: The text could have come from an IME or accessibility tool or autocomplete.